# почему Permission denied ? postgresql

Tags: sql, файлы, postgresql, запрос

Нужно из файла перевести данные в таблицу, пишу следующий запрос:
`COPY  tab  FROM 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\tab.unl' (DELIMITER '|');`

но он мне выдает `ОШИБКА:  не удалось открыть файл "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\tab.unl" для чтения: Permission denied` не знаю почему так, может где с синтаксисом ошибся в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Похоже, что у вас нет прав на выполнение этой операции.

Comment: Имеется вполне внятное описание ошибки, нет прав на чтение данного файла. Дело в том, что PostgreSQL сервис работает под собственной учеткой, файл же ему подпихивается из пользовательской папки учетки Admin, доступ к которой только данный пользователь и имеет. Перенести файлик из пользовательской папки в общии (пусть хоть корень диска, лишь бы не C:\Users\Admin), и все будет хорошо.